# HTML img code does not work?

Tags: media, wysiwyg, theming

I'm using Drupal7 with CK editör.

When I add html code for an image (`<img src="..."`)
I can see it on the editing page; but when I save it, I can't see anything on the page.

How can I solv it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your text formats (Admin > Configuration > Content Authoring > Text formats) and make sure the one you're selecting for your node isn't filtering out the img tag.

Comment: Hello,

I've chekd it but there is no problem in this section.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you notice any other tags being stripped out or just img?

Comment: Only img tag does not work. When I visit edit area, I can see image that I added before.

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to @reallyxloco.

Thanks alot!